# Command not found after installing php

Tags: php, macos, composer-php, osx-yosemite

I have php5 installed on my macbook then I tried to update it, to php7 after I successfully installed the php7, I tried to check the installed version using `php -v.` But to my surprise it shows I still have php5 running on my system. 
After that I tried to move my php7 to my php5 directory `/bin/usr/` but failed. Then I tried to run `php-v` but the response I got was **-bash: command not found**. 
Please how can I solve this both on my terminal and VSCode?

Comment: Please share more details - how is this related to Composer?

Comment: How did you install PHP 7? Did you use Homebrew? What commands did you execute and what was the (relevant) output? Most likely you now have 2 installations (one in /usr/bin/php and one somewhere else, maybe /usr/local/bin/php) and need to tell your command line, which one to use by default

Comment: @dbrumann  yes i have 2 installed already. how can i do it that i will use the most recent one i just  installed. i also just went to the root folder now and deleted the two php installed in  /usr/bin/php and /usr/local/bin/php.

Comment: @NicoHaase i was trying to use composer but i found out i won't be able to use it with the version of php installed on my system have been on this issue for over 48hours please help me. i have tried everything possible and thou i was able to install the composer manually but i can not run a command to make use of swiftmailer `composer require "swiftmailer/swiftmailer:^6.0" `  both in my vscode and terminal

Comment: Deleting the files will probably cause more problems than help. The php in /usr/bin/php is provided by your mac and probably is outdated. Just ignore it. The one in /usr/local/php is the one you installed and should be the newer one. You can choose which one is used by updating the order in which each path is read from the environment variable `$PATH`. Check your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` or similar file for where PATH is set and then change the order (usr/local/bin before /usr/bin). See here for an explanation: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/

Comment: @dbrumann please how can i set it to default that i won't have to set path everytime i want to make use of the terminal. I also want to use swiftmailer but i have not be able to run this command  `composer require "swiftmailer/swiftmailer:^6.0"` even after installing composer.

Comment: @dbrumann please how can i access i can see that it has already been installed.

Comment: You have change your PATH in your config file, `.bashrc`, `.profile` or `.zshrc`. It depends on your system. In my case it's the last one, where I have the following line: `export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`